# Api SecurityTokenExpiredExceptions in App Insights logs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, azure-application-insights

We have an angular application that gets an access token from identity server and uses it to connect to an aspnetcore api application.

I have added the authentication to the API application with
authenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer()

In Azure Application Insights logs for the Api i get a lot of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredExceptions but they don't affect the functionality.
IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: '03/30/2020 02:28:05', Current time: '04/01/2020 22:26:59'.
Does anyone know why this happens or how to remove the chatter from the logs?

Is it possibly because someone has left the browser open for a day and it still has the old access token? Should I poll the Api after a period of time and then make it get a new access token?

Answer (score 0):

Check your IdentityServer's server and API-application's server DateTime, make sure they are correct and the same.

Comment: They are both Azure App Service.
When I get the time in the console they are identical.